# Show or Hide a UIButton in iPhone app with Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `UITextView` to edit text. I want to use two `UIButtons` Edit and Save. Initially I want to show edit `UIButton`, when the user click on edit I want to show save `UIButton`. when the content successfully saved I dont want to show save button any more.

I am a c# coder, in c# I used to do like this

```
C# code
btnedit.visible=true;
```

Now I want to know how to make a button visible and not visible from objective c code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Since `UIButton` inherits from `UIView`, you can just set the `hidden` property on the button (via [UIButton doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-hidden?language=objc))

```
button.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Hi @Benny or @Pang, what is the difference between using the property `hidden` and the method `setHidden`? There are performance issues?

Answer (score 6):

Consider enabling or disabling the buttons instead. You get the same end result, but it's a little bit more consistent since things aren't appearing and dissapearing out of nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of visible, the property you are looking for is hidden.

```
saveButton.hidden = YES;
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add IBoutlet property in  .h file. like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resendOtpButtom;
```

then add

```
_resendOtpButtom.hidden = YES; in .m file.
```