# set timer to change an UIButton properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, timer, uibutton

How can I make a timer that change the properties of a UIButton from hidden to show, and from show to hidden alternating between 4 buttons?

I'm using xCode 4.4

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't know exactly what to do, but I've tried to use a timer inside a touch down event, but even if this is right, I don't know how to change the properties by codes.

Comment: timer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519562/how-do-i-write-a-timer-in-objective-c

show/hide:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957821/show-or-hide-a-uibutton-in-iphone-app-with-obejctive-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                      target: self
                      selector:@selector(onTick:)
                      userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
```

And, onTick method should look like this

```
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
   //This is where you need to set your button hidden property.
}
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer) out.It's well detailed.